# If $p,q \in B(\mathcal{H})$ are projections and $q\mathcal{H} \subset p\mathcal{H}$, show that $p\mathcal{H} = q\mathcal{H} \oplus (p-q)\mathcal{H}$.

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, projection

I was given the question: If $p,q \in B(\mathcal{H})$ are projections such that $q\mathcal{H}\subset p\mathcal{H}$, show that $p-q$ is a projection with $p\mathcal{H}= q\mathcal{H}\oplus (p-q)\mathcal{H}$.

Is my proof below rigorous enough?

If $q\mathcal{H}\subset p\mathcal{H}$, then $p$ acts as identity on $q\mathcal{H}$, and
$$
(p-q)^2 = p^2 - 2pq + q^2 = p - 2q + q = p -q
$$
and
$$
    (p-q)^* = p^* - q^* = p -q
$$
since they are projections. Thus $(p-q)$ is a projection. If $v \in \mathcal{H}$ then we can write $v = qv + (1-q)v$ and then applying $p$ across the equation we get
$$
    pv = pqv + p(1-q)v = qv + (p-pq)v = qv + (p-q)v 
$$
to show the decomposition we want.

Comment: Careful. $(p-q)^2=p^2-2pq+q^2$ iff $p$ and $q$ commute... are you sure such is the case? I’d suggest noting instead $q=pq$, $p-q=p(I-q)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks! I usually catch that sort of thing, whoops!